# Displaying data which was passed from Controller to View in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-query-builder

I am having a problem with displaying array which was retrieved from database table
This is how my array looks.

Note i selected from my database  table

```
"WHERE pro_cat_id = 36" ;

Array
(

 Array
  (
    [0] => Array
    (
        [pro_cat_id] => 1
        [cat_name] => men
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [pro_cat_id] => 2
        [cat_name] => women
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [pro_cat_id] => 3
        [cat_name] => Gilamlar
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [pro_cat_id] => 4
        [cat_name] => kids
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [pro_cat_id] => 5
        [cat_name] => others
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [pro_cat_id] => 27
        [cat_name] => game
    )

)
```

This is  My Controller's index code

```
    public function index()
    {
        $res = $this->Categories_model->getCategory();
        //  ;
        // print_r($data);
        $data = $res;

            echo "<br><br><br><pre>";
            print_r($data);
            echo "</pre>";
        $this->load->view('categories',$data);
    }
```

where getCategory is  a model function to retrive all row from database table

I tried `echo` it as `($pro_cat_id and $cat_name )`

How can i use this data in view?

How to pass Multidimensional array to view and use it there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

Your `index` method should be like this :

```
public function index()
{
    $data['categories'] = $this->Categories_model->getCategory();
    // print_r($data);
    $this->load->view('categories',$data);
}
```

In your `categories` view page use `foreach` loop  like this :

```
<?php 
  if (! empty($categories))
  {
    foreach ($categories as $category)
    { 
      echo $category['pro_cat_id'];
      echo $category['cat_name'];
    }
  }

?>
```